# How do I removed the breadcrumb from the front page?

Tags: 7, theming, breadcrumbs

I am trying to remove the breadcrumb from the front page. I am using the Bartik theme. I have a page--front.tpl.php template file and I tried to removing the following code lines.

```php
<?php if ($logo): ?>
  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo">
    <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```php
<?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
  <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I just realized that my front page isn't picking up the page--front.tpl template. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be the [Disable breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/disable_breadcrumbs) module. The pros of the modules are that writing code is not necessary and it is independent from the theme; in this way, you don't need to alter the theme each time you change the theme being used.

> Disable breadcrumbs on a per node, per content type, or by path (any
>   path) basis; Omitting the need to write additional code in the theme
>   layer (template.php file etc..) to determine the visibilty of
>   breadcrumbs on specific pages. This can be administered on node edit
>   forms and from the content administration page (node operations) to
>   select/unselect multiple nodes for enabled types.

Answer (score 1):

You can also comment them out on the page.tpl.php like so

```
<?php /* if ($breadcrumb): ?>
       <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
   <?php endif; */?>
```

And then if you want them back later... take the /* s out. :)

Comment: This would be for the entire tho...

Comment: comment on if condition will not hide the breadcrumb

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this code.

```
if (!$is_front && !empty($breadcrumb)) {
  print $breadcrumb; 
}
```

Otherwise, go to your theme folder and remove the code in page.tpl.php. This will be remove the breadcrumbs from your site.

Be careful: It will completely remove the breadcrumbs. If you want to get them back later, then keep the code in another file.

This is the code for the Bartik theme.

```
<?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
  <div id="breadcrumb">
    <?php print $breadcrumb; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```